# One of the json.dumps values is null

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-authentication, parsley.js

I'm setting up a front-end user authentication check with Parsley.js and Django.
This is my view

```
@requires_csrf_token
def password_check(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password1')
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if user and user.is_active:
            res = "These password and e-mail are ok."
            ajax_vars_login = {'response': res, 'email': email, 'password': password}
            json_data_login = json.dumps(ajax_vars_login)
        else:
            res = "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct."
            ajax_vars_login = {'response': res, 'email': email, 'password': password}
            json_data_login = json.dumps(ajax_vars_login)

        return HttpResponse(json_data_login, content_type='application/json')
```

And this is the Parsley validator:

```
Parsley.addAsyncValidator(
  'emailPwCombination', function (xhr) {
       var password = $('#password').parsley();
       var email = $('#email').parsley();
       var response = xhr.responseText;
       var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
       var jsonResponseText = jsonResponse["response"];

       if(jsonResponseText == 'These password and e-mail are ok.')
           return true;
       if(jsonResponseText == '404')
           return false;
  }, '/password_check/'
);
```

The problem is it seems that the email isn't sent to the server, because whenever I press on submit, I get two xhr responses.
The first response:

```
{password: null, response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct.",…}
email: "example@gmail.com"
password: null
response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct."
```

The second response:

```
{password: "examplepassword", response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct.", email: null}
email: null
password: "examplepassword"
response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct."
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

This code is inside an async validator, so each time you call `.parsley()` on a value, it sends it to the backend. So you'll get two separate requests, one containing just the email and one containing just the password.

I don't think you've understood what parsley is for. It's for validation of individual fields according to a set of criteria; not for sending a full form of data to the backend for processing. This can be done very simply in a few lines of basic jQuery, no need for parsley here at all.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was either for individual fields convalidation and for form processing. Thank you for your answer :)